# How to run a unit testing particular component in angular 4

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Is there any way to run a unit test only for a particular component in the angular 4 project?

Comment: Add f to `describe` to focus it. Use `fdescribe`. This will run only the focused component.

Answer (score 1):

Add f to `describe` keyword to focus it. Use `fdescribe`. This will run only the focused component.

```
fdescribe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));


  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run one test then use `fit`. if set of tests  then use `fdescribe`

```
describe('sample', () => {


  fit('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually manually change the context in `src/test.ts`

from this (runs all tests):

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

to the name of the test file i want to run:

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /login.service.spec\.ts$/);
```

This is based on your test file only testing the component.